# modifying background

Tags: html, image, background

I am a beginner in HTML and am taking a Multimedia class for school. I noticed for many websites such as ESPN, CNN, Google, etc. that there was no direct image source for the entire background. How might I be able to incorporate an image for an entire background of a website? Thanks I appreciate it!

---

OH ok I see the problem, I was in HTML, not CSS. So where do I find the source file? I know in HTML if there is a image placed it will usually be followed by something like img src etc., and the image I want to use I usually copy the image location and paste, is this the same for this? Also I see in the CSS script the words

```
body {
 margin:0;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like that?

With CSS:

body
{
background-image:url('myImage.gif');
}

Your question is not so clear though...

Comment: OH ok I see the problem, I was in HTML, not CSS. So where do I find the source file? I know in HTML if there is a image placed it will usually be followed by something like img src etc., and the image I want to use I usually copy the image location and paste, is this the same for this? Also I see in the CSS script the words

body { margin:0;

Where do I implement from here? (

Thanks Rabidmachine! youre a great help

Comment: Ok I would suggest starting reading some articles about css and html...
I find this really usefull(css): http://www.sitepoint.com/books/cssant3/

also some websites like that:http://www.w3schools.com/(good just to start...)
I mean you seem to luck some basic knowledge here(I don't pretend to be guru but do some reading before posting questions because you seem to be in a real hurry.

also never answer your own questions just comment or edit!
the best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add the background image into your HTML, I would add it to the body div:

```
<body background="blue.jpg">
```

If you want to add it to your CSS or stylesheet, use this:

```
body {background: url(blue.jpg); }
```

Does that answer your question?